# Xdebug: What Drupal values for "Project URL" & "Index File" will NetBeans accept for a new Configuration?

Tags: debugging, views

I just slept at a Holiday Inn last night and watched this [Vimeo Tut on Xdebug](http://vimeo.com/35981390). I'm experiencing trouble with a Views plugin and wish to "step into the Matrix" to find where the error is occurring.

In NetBeans each project is set up with a default URL and template file. These are set from `File >> Project Properties -- Configuration (New)`. I have Netbeans and Xdebug working. The project default is the site home url and the top [drupal_root/] index.php file. I'm *guessing* if I make a new configuration of "Project URL" and "Index File" then Netbeans will open the project and focus my debug session to this area of Drupal. But so far the urls and index pages I'm selecting--Netbeans doesn't like.

I want to debug between the Edit View Page URL and the Configure Item URL. The error occurs between these two pages,

```
http://mysite.local/admin/structure/views/view/drag_test
```

And when I click on `Draggableviews: Weight (asc)` (under *Sort criteria*), the resulting non-JavaScript "configure item" page [*] displays the errors at the top,

```
http://mysite.local/admin/structure/views/nojs/config-item/drag_test/page/sort/weight
```

I'm guessing the views template, views-ui-edit-item.tpl, is what I want. Netbeans of course wants an index file, but in Drupal that's the top page.

**What Drupal values for "Project URL" & "Index File" will NetBeans accept for a new Configuration?**

---

[*] FYI. In case you're not immediately familiar with what a non-JavaScript Edit View Page is, remember how it was in Drupal 6 with options at the bottom of the page? Only in D7 options display on a new page when JavaScript overlay is off. (^_^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick to target a specific page using NetBeans and xDebug is to use Arguments.

```
File >> Project Properties >> Run Configuration
Project URL: http://hellofrom.local/
Index File: index.php
Arguments: q=admin/structure/views/view/post_drag/edit/page_1
```